# Android Google Maps ошибка в старых версиях SDK

Tags: android, google-maps-api, android-fragment, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

Работаю с Google Maps.

Есть два устройства один на SDK 23, другой на SDK 18.

По порядку:

Манифест:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ru.suite.name.project">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <uses-permission android:name="ru.suite.name.project.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"  android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />

    <!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <!--<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />-->

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

......
```

Разметка:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/map_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <fragment
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/searchMy"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_track_changes_100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_circle_selector"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:onClick="onClickSearchMyLocation" />
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Инициализация карты. Я карту поместил во фрагмент.

```
public class fragment_new_order_map extends Fragment {

GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new_order_map, container, false);
        return v;
    }

@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (googleMap != null) {


            }
        }
    }

}
```

**В чем проблема:**

Когда я запускаю программу на устройстве с SDK 23, все хорошо! 
Мало того, все хорошо даже если я поменяю в манифесте:

```
<meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
                android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

на

```
<meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

Так и так все отлично работает!

Проблема с устройством на SDK 18.

При попытки инициализировать карту выдает вот такую ошибку:

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error
>   inflating class fragment
>                                                                                           at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:719)
>                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
>                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
>                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
>                                                                                           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
>                                                                                           at
>   ru.suite.name.project.fragments.fragment_new_order_map.onCreateView(fragment_new_order_map.java:99)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
>                                                                                           at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:517)
>                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
>                                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>                                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
>                                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
>                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>                                                                                           at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
>                                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
>                                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that
>    is in the  element of
>   AndroidManifest.xml

**UPD**
При этом - стандартный проект из примера в Android Studio работает на всех устройствах. 
Единственная разница между проектами что я использую карты во фрагментах, а в примере в  FragmentActivity.

**UPD2**
Я думаю что проблема в

```
googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
```

Он по какой то причине не может найти - R.id.map и возвращает NULL. Может проблема в том, что я обращаюсь через getChildFragmentManager а сам R.id.map лежит на фрагменте который только что создался?! Но тогда, почему данная логика работает на SDK 23!?!!?!?

Answer (score 1):

Все, разобрался! Дело в моей невнимательности.

Просто ключ почему то был в ресурсах для API 21. И я этого не замечал. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found
```

Вы точно в консоли разработчика получили Ваш ключ для maps api?

Comment: Да, иначе как бы работало на SDK 23 ?? Ключ получен. Все сделано в точности как и по примеру Android только перенесено все во фрагмент. Если кстати в примере от Android Studio , карту перенести во фрагмент то она тоже перестает работать.